# Matching OAuth request to response

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

Focussing on the authorization_code grant type (server to server) I am confused as to how a client (in this case a web server app) matches a response (positive) to the outgoing request.

The response is a redirect with code in the URL (not interested in the token part yet). How does the web server know who this code belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with OAuth now for a couple of weeks I understand now how this works.

If we are talking about granting application A logged in user U authorisation to access resource R.

1. The user U starts off in application A and is logged in there in the browser which means in most cases that a cookie is set with a session token.
2. The user U is redirected to application / resource R where he would login (or be automatically logged in using a resource R session cookie).
3. Presuming he grants the request he is then redirected in the browser back to application A with a code C.
4. Here again the seesion cookie for application A from step 1 is presented to the server but along with the code C. The server of application A can then use this code to get a token for the user U.